# Sleep analysis app / device for iPhone

Tags: ipad-app, iphone-app

Nowadays I have bad dreams and I am looking for an iOS app / EEG device that can measure electronic brain activity / store data in Health app / device can bought on a  reasonable price.

I googled it, but I did not found solution meet all criteria.

Anyway I would be interested for this device able to use with iPhone  together

`EEG` (electroencephalogram) to measure and record brain wave activity

`EMG` (electromyogram) to record muscle activity such as face twitches, teeth grinding, and leg movements; it also helps in determining the presence of REM stage sleep.

`EOG` (electro-oculogram) to record eye movements; these movements are important in determining the different sleep stages, particularly REM stage sleep.

`EKG` (electrocardiogram) to record heart rate and rhythm

Comment: I would recommend seeing a doctor instead. Seriously.

Comment: If there's such an app I would love to know about it too. Have no problems with my sleep, but the fact that it's too short due to my busy schedule.

Comment: [Sleep Cycle](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/sleep-cycle-alarm-clock/id320606217) is able to chart different sleep stage but not connect to any ExG